Does taking input of the user's Codeforces handle in a Chrome extension require a privacy policy to be published by the developer?
I have build a chrome extension which is used to monitor user's and their friends codeforces rating and to fetch their rating I am taking input from user of their codeforces handle. So does it requires a privacy policy to be published by me for this?
I have not tried anything till now, just asking before publishing?

StackOverflow is for programming-related questions, while this one is about policy of the web store. Try asking for an official reply in the extensions group.
